# shortest paths lengths on .off file with python

Tags: python-3.x, graph, shapes

I am dealing with a set of 3D shapes in a .off format (the ModelNet10 http://3dshapenets.cs.princeton.edu/), that is, I basically have access to a `N x 3` array for `(x,y,z)` coordinates for vertices and another `N x 3` array of faces, telling me that face `[i,j,k]` belong to the shape (̀`i,j,k` being vertex indices), in particular edges `[i,j], [i,k], [j,k]` belong to the underlying graph (1 dimensional skeleton).

I wonder what is the best way to get the matrix of geodesic (shortest paths) distances with such shapes, essentially using Python3 (or another standard language like C++ or R, but will need some help then). Here, "best" ideally means "optmized for 3D triangular shapes", but "that efficiently works" would be satisfying too.

Right now, my idea is to build the underlying (undirected, weighted) graph for a given shape. I could then use scipy csgraph (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html). That might sounds very simple, but I did not find a library doing that for me yet. I could implement that by myself but I need something a bit optimized and would prefer to rely on some time-proved code.

**My current attempts:**

- Using PyMesh (https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to load my .off files (getting the two `N x 3` arrays mentionned above). I would think that PyMesh offers a way to simply build the corresponding graph but did not find it yet.
- Another trial: using gudhi (http://gudhi.gforge.inria.fr/python/latest/) that allow to load a simplex_tree (with dim = 1 in my case) from a .off file. There might be a simple way to build the (geodesic ?) distances matrix from that (or to feed scipy with this), but it's a bit messy to me too.
- Maybe something with networkx (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) but once again, it's not clear to me how to make this library interact with the others.

Of course, there might be some library I don't know about doing the trick, or that could interact well with the aforementionned ones.

Thanks !

Comment: PS : if needed, note that I only need shortest paths **lengths** between vertices, I don't care about shortest paths in themselves.

Comment: There is nothing about computing geodesics in Gudhi. Mael Rouxel-Labbé
implemented the algorithm described in Campen, M., Heistermann, M., and Kobbelt, L. Practical anisotropic geodesy. In Pro- ceedings of the Eleventh Eurographics/ACMSIGGRAPH Symposium on Geometry Processing (2013), SGP ’13, Eurographics Association, pp. 63–71.

which seems to be the most efficient algorithm for triangulated surfaces. The implementation is in C++ and uses CGAL.